# Exclude certain changes (additions and deletions) to branch when merging, but keep tracking them in their branches

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I'm a new user to git, but I've used tHg before, and I'm familiar with the basic stuff of branching and merging. (say, up to using diff tool and resolving conflicts with it)
I'm using tortoiseGit to do my work for me, so I can have windows explorer/shell integration. I lack a piece of knowledge on merging using tGit/git. (or better said: I've never try to do anything like this with any SCM before)

I have started a repository from an existing code base. With my new git repo, I've branched off a dev and a test branch. The old code base I started my repo with already included some tests.

Now I'd like to version those tests so I can roll back stuff in the test branch if a test proves to be wrong or something. I think just ignoring them won't be the solution, unless there's a way to still version them in the test branch. I would like to delete my tests from the dev branch so I have a (much) cleaner project file structure in the dev branch, but keep them in the test branch. So, if I delete the tests, the deletion should propagate from the dev branch to the test branch when I update the code to test, right? That's what I don't want to happen. Is there a way to not propagate the deletions?

So, is it possible to push only a selected set of file changes back from dev to test and vice versa? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Sure: on the tests branch do a `-s ours` merge of the dev-branch commit that deletes all the tests.  But it seems to me you want to version the tests entirely separately from the source. You could go all submodule-y on it, but for something like this just keep them in entirely separate branches from which you merge onto your "testing" branch:

```
T---o---o-------o        tests (contains tests/*)
         \       \
          1---2---3      testing
         /   /   /
D---o---o---o---o        dev   (contains all but tests/*)
```

To start the tests branch,

```
git checkout --orphan tests
ls|grep -v tests|xargs git rm -r
git commit -m"just the tests"
```

To do your testing it's

```
git checkout testing  (#git checkout -B testing the first time)
git merge dev tests
# test test fix fix commit commit
```

and then if the testing did produce the fix fix commit commit part, selectively merge back:

```
# selective merges from testing
git checkout tests
git merge -s ours --no-commit testing
git checkout --theirs tests    # or however else you want to select fixes
git commit

git checkout dev
git merge -s ours --no-commit testing
git checkout --theirs path/to/fixed/this and/so/on   # likewise
# or git checkout --theirs .; git rm -rf tests
git commit
```

or you can do two-stepper mergebacks:

```
# selective merges from testing

git checkout -B from-testing testing
# rm everything but tests/*
git add -A; git commit
git checkout tests
git merge from-testing

git checkout -B from-testing testing
# rm tests/*
git add -A; git commit
git checkout dev
git merge from-testing
```

As you get more comfortable with this kind of stuff you'll be able to avoid the unnecessary worktree manipulations with resets rather than checkouts, on a large project learning that can be worthwhile.

Comment: Nice answer! I'm going to read up on the things you've just mentioned. Do you happen to know how to do the things you just mentioned with tortoiseGit? I'm not much of a cmd user.

Comment: Thank you.  re TG, I don't, it's probably bias but I doubt whether anything beyond pidgin usage is within its reach.